# Can Ubuntu Core be installed and does it run very well on the nexus 10?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-core, nexus-10

Recently I've bought a Nexus 10 tablet. I did install Ubuntu Touch and do not find it ready for daily use. I have reinstalled Android 4.4.2. Since I don't like Android, I have in mind to install the Ubuntu Core and then choose the packages and drivers.

I have read: http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/features/graphics-and-compute-development-on-samsung-chromebook. This article says that it works for an Samsung Chromebook. I think that - with some modifications- that it could work on the Nexus 10 because the Chromebook shares the same hardware specifications with the Nexus 10. For example the same CPU and the same graphic chip set. The boot procedure is different, but booting shouldn't be a problem because I have already unlocked the device, after reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Do you think that my idea can be realized?

Comment: Also I would like to find some tutorial that helps me,because I'm not an advanced user and I don't know to start this project by myself only.

Comment: please give a look here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install on the section "Manual Download & Installation". I would like to know how to look inside this file : "system saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img". I'm not able to mount it with this command : mount -o loop system saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img /mnt,because the error is : you have to specify the filesystem type...

Answer (score 0):

Your original question that's posted in the title "*can it run very well on the nexus 10*?" is relative because I don't know what kind of user you are.

I've used "Complete Linux Installer" before and it ran well on my Galaxy S3 with **very basic uses.** It did run well for the browser, Libre Office, etc.

To finalize my answer, **it shouldn't be a problem. I think it's a good, feasible idea.** If I can do it with little annoyance on my Galaxy S3, you can surely do it on the Nexus 10 with even less annoyance. I personally prefer Android, but that's relative. It will work on Nexus 10 with little modification.

That's pretty much all I have to say, other than once you respond. You can take a look at the Android thread articles on my site. On the main page (gymforgeeks.com) I'm actually writing a tutorial on this soon.